# SQLite Database from Internet

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have a rather large database that ships with my app. I'm having a lot of trouble getting it to properly create itself on the local device, so I figure with the issues and it being so large, it might make more sense to host it on a server and work with it from there.

The database is 40 MB or less. What is the best way to manage this with it hosted somewhere?

Comment: store it in sdcard and use [openDatabase](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#openDatabase(java.lang.String, android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory, int)) manage it?

Comment: I don't really understand. I have the database stored in the assets and previously I used code to copy it to the user's phone. Any attempt to store the code in sdcard failed. Is there no way to host it remotely?

Comment: The sqlite db file is of 40MB which has to be kept in assets folder? If so, it depends on you to decide. If you decide to maintain the database remotely, you might need to use other database with some scripting language like servlets or php etc.,

Comment: If I decide not to do it remotely, and keep it in my app locally, is there a way to put it somewhere besides Assets and still use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with `Database file` size. You can make a `Zip` of your `Database` file and then copy it to your local path from `Assets`.

Here is the link: [Copy Db File From Assets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5945059/how-to-use-sqlite-connection-from-asset-folder/5950967#5950967)

Now, in that code replace the `copyDataBase()` function with the below one.

```
private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {
    try {
       InputStream mInputStream = mContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME_ZIP);
       String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME_ZIP;
       OutputStream mOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
       byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
       int length;
       while ((length = mInputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
          mOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
       }

       ZipFile mZipFile = new ZipFile(DB_PATH + DB_NAME_ZIP);
       InputStream nInputStream = mZipFile.getInputStream(mZipFile.getEntry(DB_NAME));
       OutputStream nOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);
       while ((length = nInputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
          nOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
       }
       nOutputStream.flush();
       nOutputStream.close();
       nInputStream.close();

       // Close the streams
       mOutputStream.flush();
       mOutputStream.close();
       mInputStream.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
       //Delete Zip file to minimize memory usage
       final String mPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME_ZIP;
       final File file = new File(mPath);
       if (file.exists())
          file.delete();
    }
}
```

- Here `DB_NAME_ZIP` is the `Database Zip` file what you put in `Assets` folder like `Android.zip` but it actually contains `Android.sqlite` or `Android.db`.

I hope this one can help you.

Comment: I need the adapter class too? I didn't need it when I used the DataBaseHelper class from this link: http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/
It seems like a lot of extra work to use the adapter. Is it possible to use your method with the code I'm using?

Comment: @rar Yes It is possible to use my method inside your code but please be careful as I separated all methods among two class `DatabaseHelper` and `DBAdpater`.

Comment: Will this solve the issue of creating on the device, or just succeed in keeping the size of the database down?

Comment: @rar Yes it will solve the issue of creating on the device as well. I tried this code with `Database` file size `~10MB` and it is working perfectly.

Comment: Thanks this works! Loading time is slow now, but I'll do some optimizations to fix that.